# Different AWS CLI identity when running script via Java's Runtime.getRuntime() inside AWS ECS node that runs a Spring Boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-cli

I have the following setup:

- A docker image on which Java 17 and AWS CLI v2 are installed.
- The docker image also contains:

  - A Spring Boot app
  - A `/test-identity.sh` script that executes only `aws sts get-caller-identity` inside.
- The image is deployed in AWS ECS and there is a task role and an EC2 instance role defined in IAM for the task and the service.

**When I use the AWS SDK for Java within the Java code, then that is using the credentials of the task role, as expected.**

I perform the following two tests:

1. I SSH into the ECS node and I execute the following:

> docker exec -it e15f498e4ca0 /bin/bash
>
> /test-identity.sh

2. I add some Java code in the Spring Boot like the following:

> Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash", "-lc", "/test-identity.sh")

The result of test #1 is different than #2. The output of test #1 gives me the service's task role (as exepcted) while the output of #2 gives me the EC2 instance role (not expected).

My goal is to make #2 output the task role too, since I want that script to use the same credentials as the Java code (when run via Java code).

Is this possible?

Comment: There's a difference between an ECS Task Role: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html and an ECS Task Execution Role: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_execution_IAM_role.html Your question is unclear as to if you actually have a Task Role since you mention "Task Execution Role" once. Please ensure you are assigning a Task Role that you want the software running in your container to use.

Comment: Thank you, @MarkB, but I'm aware of the difference. But you were right that my description was misleading, so I edited it now to be more clear.